# Yii2, how to use or operator in rest request

Tags: yii2

I am trying to use or operator in my rest request Yii2 but I cannot succeed.
Everytime I have this error :
[
    {
        "field": "filter",
        "message": "Operator \"or\" requires multiple operands."
    }
]

I tested several things but nothing works.

I want to filter
statut=0 or statut=1

Do you know or I can do it ?

I tried to
http://url/api/tickets/gestions?filter[or][statut][statut]=[0,1]

But it does not work

Here's the method within controller that manage this request :

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    return ActionsHelper::actionIndex(
        $this->modelClass,
        $this->modelClass . 'Search'
    );
}
```

$this->modelClass is defined above and is equal to 'api\modules\tickets\models\TicketGestion';

Here is ActionsHelper::actionIndex

```
public function actionIndex($model, $searchModel = null, $moreFilter = null, 
$pagination = false)
{
    $filterCondition = null;

    if ($searchModel) {
        $filter = new ActiveDataFilter([
            'searchModel' => $searchModel
        ]);


        if ($filter->load(\Yii::$app->request->get())) { 
            $filterCondition = $filter->build();
            if ($filterCondition === false) {
                return $filter;
            }
        }
    }

    $query = $model::find();

    if ($filterCondition !== null) {
        $query->andWhere($filterCondition);
    }

    if ($moreFilter !== null) {
        $query->andWhere($moreFilter);
    }

    if ($pagination !== false) {
        $pagination = [
            'pageSize' => 100
        ];
    }

    return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => $pagination
    ]);
}
```

Here's the search model, generated by Gii

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\tickets\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use api\modules\tickets\models\TicketGestion;

/**
 * TicketGestionSearch represents the model behind the search form of `api\modules\tickets\models\TicketGestion`.
 */
class TicketGestionSearch extends TicketGestion
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'priorite', 'quicree', 'quirea', 'statut', 'recurrentid', 'typerea', 'client'], 'integer'],
            [['dispatch', 'service', 'type', 'sujet', 'datecrea', 'dateecheance', 'daterea'], 'safe'],
            [['duree'], 'number'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = TicketGestion::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        if ($this->dispatch == 'null') {
            $this->dispatch = 1;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'priorite' => $this->priorite,
            'quicree' => $this->quicree,
            'quirea' => $this->quirea,
            'datecrea' => $this->datecrea,
            'dateecheance' => $this->dateecheance,
            'daterea' => $this->daterea,
            'duree' => $this->duree,
            'statut' => $this->statut,
            'recurrentid' => $this->recurrentid,
            'typerea' => $this->typerea,
            'client' => $this->client,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'service', $this->service])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'type', $this->type])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'sujet', $this->sujet])
            ->andFilterWhere(['likes', 'dispatch', $this->dispatch]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Actualy there is no code I have to show for this.

It is just an url and I am trying to use the filtering given by https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start

Comment: If you write that you try and there is some error, then there is something to show)

Comment: I edited my post with code, thanks for your answer

Comment: add search model too.

Comment: I added the Search Model in my main post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on a right track, using ActiveDataFilter, but building arrays from get is done like this (example is from my controller):

```
http://localhost/ntb/web/index.php?r=assembly%2Findex&filter[or][0][status]=1004&filter[or][1][status]=1005&page=1&per-page=10
```

so for your example it should be like this:

```
 http://url/api/tickets/gestions?filter[or][0][statut]=0&filter[or][1][statut]=1
```

This was the way to build a working 'or' filter for me.

Comment: For me worked as filter[or][][status]=0&filter[or][][status][like]=1